# Ms access 2013 vba to scan an attach file to an attachment field. vba won't save record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, recordset

In access 2013, I'm using a form (called "Table1") linked to a table that has an attachment field that I'm adding a scanned document (bmp) to.  There are two textboxes that I use to name the scanned document on the form. Everything works if I input the record then hit save and then click my button (called testButton), but if I don't hit save, the attachment saves to the last record or a few records back. I'm pretty sure it's a saving issue, because when I try to scan and attach after the computer has been dormant, it works just fine, I'm guessing autosave. However, if I'm trying to scan multiple records back to back, the attachment goes to the previous record if I don't hit save on the ribbon. I've tried placing

```
DoCmd.Save acForm, "Table1"
```

or

```
If Me.Dirty Then
Me.Dirty = False

   MsgBox ("File Saved")

   End If
```

or even

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

at different points in the code to no avail. The DoCmd functions save the record, but start the recordset at the first record, not the one I'm currently inputting. So instead of attaching to the second to last record, it attaches to the first record.

My goal is to be able to hit the button and it work perfectly without having to hit save. I even looked for a code that does exactly what the save button on the ribbon does to no avail.

Here is the current code I'm using.

```
Option Compare Database
Dim FileLocation As String
Dim diagFile As FileDialog






Private Sub testButton_Click()

'DoCmd.Save acForm, "Table1" (Commented out, because it's not working)

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset2

If Me.Dirty Then

  Me.Dirty = False

   MsgBox ("File Saved")

   End If

Me.testBox = Me.Payment & Me.Merchant ' I use this to see the input on screen



ScanImage

AttachImage



End Sub

Private Sub ScanImage()

'This method works, it's the AttachImage that's causing issues.

   Set diagFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

   diagFile.Title = "Save Bitmap File As..."
   diagFile.InitialFileName = Me.Payment & " " & Me.Merchant & ".bmp"

   diagFile.Show
    FileLocation = diagFile.SelectedItems(1)

   Dim scanDiag As New WIA.CommonDialog
   Dim image As WIA.ImageFile

   Set image = scanDiag.ShowAcquireImage(ScannerDeviceType)
   image.SaveFile FileLocation



   MsgBox ("File Saved")
'   MsgBox (CurrentRecord) I used this to see on screen the record I'm inputing



End Sub

 Private Sub AttachImage()



 MsgBox ("Step 1 attaching") ' I use this and all the MsgBoxes to see where in the code the procedure is.




 'MsgBox ("Step 2 attaching")

On Error GoTo Err_AddImage
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsParent = Me.Recordset

rsParent.Edit

Set rsChild = rsParent.Fields("Receipt").Value

'MsgBox "Nombre el archivo: " & rsChild("FileName").Value
'MsgBox "Tipo de archivo: " & rsChild.Fields("FileType").Value
'MsgBox "Data del archivo: " & rsChild.Fields("FileData").Value
'Do Until rsChild.EOF
'        For Each fld In rsChild.Fields
'          Debug.Print fld
'        Next fld
'  rsChild.MoveNext
'  Loop

 'MsgBox ("Step 3 attaching")


rsChild.AddNew
rsChild.Fields("FileData").LoadFromFile ("C:\Users\omoawotona\Desktop\Receipt Clone\" & Me.Payment & " " & Me.Merchant & ".bmp")

rsChild.Update
rsParent.Update

'MsgBox ("Step 4 attaching")



Me.Refresh
'MsgBox ("Step 5 attaching")
'MsgBox ("Attachment done")

Exit_AddImage:

Set rsChild = Nothing
Set rsParent = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_AddImage:

If Err = 3820 Then
MsgBox ("File already part of the multi-valued field!")
Me.Refresh
Resume Next

Else
MsgBox "Some Other Error occured!", Err.Number, Err.Description
Resume Exit_AddImage

End If




 End Sub
```